# Горячие клавиши для Visual Studio 2022

Tags: hotkeys, visual-studio-2022

Можно ли использовать сочетание клавиш для создания папки в проекте? К примеру, нажать на папку "MyFolder" находящаяся внутри проекта (не в решении), а затем комбинацией клавиш создать папку. Надеюсь, такое возможно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio из коробки позволяет назначь комбинации клавиш для любых команд меню и тулбаров. Эти настройки можно найти открыв Главное меню -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сначала установить расширение [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/resharper/) для VS, затем сделать следующие шаги:

1. `Alt + Shift + L` для перехода в Обозреватель решений;
2. `Alt + Ins` для создания папки.

Источник для данных хоткеев: https://dev.to/andreisfedotov/how-to-create-a-new-folder-in-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts-2fn4